# OAuth2 endpoint post request Xero

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, xero-api

First up, I'm not using the Xero api. This is more an OAuth2 questions than Xero specifically I think.

Not quite sure if the issue is a general OAuth2 problem or a Xero implementation of OAuth2.  I can successfully authenticate, get my tokens etc from Xero. I can even make successful Get requests to their endpoints for Invoices and contacts.  My problem is trying to POST anything, i.e. create an invoice.

The server responds with, 400 Bad request. I've confirmed by actual post data is correct by putting the XML into their API tester and all is good there.

Shouldn't a post request be a standard `httpwebequest`, (POST) with the query string `?oauth_signature=[sig here]`, and the actual post data URL encoded and sent via stream? Is my implementation correct and should I be looking elsewhere for the problem? Is the data sent in the form supposed to be included in the signature?

```
{
    byte[] reqData = encode.GetBytes(postData);

    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url + querystring) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "POST";
    try {
        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream) {
            stream.Write(reqData, 0, reqData.Length);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse) {
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            dynamic responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return responseFromServer;
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Xero uses OAuth1.0a, rather than OAuth2. The OAuth signature needs to be supplied as a header rather than a query string. I believe it should be exactly the same as the successful GET requests you're making.

https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#rfc.section.5.4.1:

> The OAuth Protocol Parameters are sent in the Authorization header the following way:
>
> Parameter names and values are encoded per Parameter Encoding.
> For each parameter, the name is immediately followed by an '=' character (ASCII code 61), a '"' character (ASCII code 34), the parameter value (MAY be empty), and another '"' character (ASCII code 34).
> Parameters are separated by a comma character (ASCII code 44) and OPTIONAL linear whitespace per [RFC2617].
> The OPTIONAL realm parameter is added and interpreted per [RFC2617], section 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Update for those finding this now, Xero API now has OAuth2 in public Beta
https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/overview